# SQL Server 2012 Powershell script to generate database with schema and data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, scripting, powershell

Using Sql Server 2012, could somebody be so kind and show me a simple powershell 3 script that generates my entire database (schema and data)?

I tried this one:

```
$Filepath='d:\b\t' # local directory to save build-scripts to
$DataSource='HH' # server name and instance
$Database='HMovies'# the database to copy from
# set "Option Explicit" to catch subtle errors
set-psdebug -strict
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop" # you can opt to stagger on, bleeding, if an error occurs
# Load SMO assembly, and if we're running SQL 2008 DLLs load the SMOExtended and SQLWMIManagement libraries
$ms='Microsoft.SqlServer'
$v = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "$ms.SMO")
if ((($v.FullName.Split(','))[1].Split('='))[1].Split('.')[0] -ne '9') {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("$ms.SMOExtended") | out-null
   }
$My="$ms.Management.Smo" #
$s = new-object ("$My.Server") $DataSource
if ($s.Version -eq  $null ){Throw "Can't find the instance $Datasource"}
$db= $s.Databases[$Database]
if ($db.name -ne $Database){Throw "Can't find the database '$Database' in $Datasource"};
$transfer = new-object ("$My.Transfer") $db
$transfer.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true # this only goes to the file
$transfer.Options.ToFileOnly = $true # this only goes to the file
$transfer.Options.ScriptData = $true;
$transfer.Options.Filename = "$($FilePath)\$($Database)_Build.sql";
$transfer.ScriptTransfer()
"All done"
```

But I get an error

```
Exception calling "ScriptTransfer" with "0" argument(s): "This method does not support scripting data."
```

If I disable the ScriptData option it works but then I get the schema only of course.
I have googled for hours but I just can't find a simple script (no bells and whistles for stored procedures, etc) that performs this simple task.

My time is running out. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you just take a backup?

Comment: I checked out the backup option and found a powershell script that does the trick. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to use Powershell to script a small database so that I can track changes in git. I found the same script you did to use as a starting point:
[Automated Script Generation with Powershell and SMO](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/)

You can find all of the options for the ScriptingOptions class here: [ScriptingOptions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.aspx)

You're getting the error because of the now deprecated `ScriptTransfer` method.

Replace this line

```
$transfer.ScriptTransfer()
```

with this

```
$transfer.EnumScriptTransfer()
```

and your script should run.

Comment: I am getting the exact same error when running the script with the second command